# wp_enqueue_scripts jquery to footer.php

Tags: jquery, wordpress, footer

I have this script in my footer.php and I like to add it to the footer.php by using wp_enqueue_scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function(){

<?php
if ( is_home() ) {

    if ( option::get('featured_posts_show') == 'on' ) {

        ?>if ( jQuery('#slider li').length > 0 ) {
            jQuery('#slider').flexslider({
                controlNav: false,
                directionNav: false,
                animationLoop: true,
                animation: '<?php echo option::get('slideshow_effect') == 'Slide' ? 'slide' : 'fade'; ?>',
                useCSS: true,
                smoothHeight: false,
                touch: false,
                slideshow: <?php echo option::get('slideshow_auto') == 'on' ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>,
                <?php if ( option::get('slideshow_auto') == 'on' ) echo 'slideshowSpeed: ' . option::get('slideshow_speed') . ','; ?>
                pauseOnAction: true,
                animationSpeed: 600,
                start: function(slider){
                    jQuery('#slider_nav .item').click(function(){
                        var id = getPostIdClass(this);
                        if ( id <= 0 ) return;

                        var index = slider.slides.index( slider.slides.filter('.' + id) );

                        slider.direction = (index > slider.currentSlide) ? 'next' : 'prev';
                        slider.flexAnimate(index, slider.pauseOnAction);
                    });
                },
                before: function(slider){
                    var id = getPostIdClass( slider.slides.eq(slider.animatingTo) );
                    if ( id <= 0 ) return;

                    jQuery('#slider_nav .item').removeClass('current');
                    jQuery('#slider_nav .item.' + id).addClass('current');

                    if ( jQuery('#slider_nav .row').length > 1 ) {
                        var navSlider = jQuery('#slider_nav').data('flexslider'),
                            currPage = navSlider.slides.index( navSlider.slides.find('.item.' + id).parent('.row') );
                        navSlider.direction = (currPage > navSlider.currentSlide) ? 'next' : 'prev';
                        navSlider.flexAnimate(currPage, navSlider.pauseOnAction);
                    }
                }
            });

            jQuery('#slider_nav .item').wrapInChunks('<div class="row" />', 4);

            jQuery('#slider_nav').flexslider({
                selector: '.tiles > .row',
                direction: 'vertical',
                controlNav: true,
                directionNav: false,
                animationLoop: false,
                animation: 'slide',
                useCSS: true,
                smoothHeight: false,
                touch: false,
                slideshow: false,
                pauseOnAction: true,
                animationSpeed: 600
            });
        }<?php

    }

    if ( option::get('carousel_posts_show') == 'on' ) {

        ?>if ( jQuery('#carousel .item').length > 0 ) {
            jQuery('#carousel .item').wrapInChunks('<div class="row" />', 3);
            jQuery('#carousel .row').append('<div class="clear" />');

            if ( jQuery('#carousel .item').length > 3 ) {
                jQuery('#carousel_wrap').append('<div id="carousel_nav"><div class="prev">Prev</div><div class="next">Next</div></div>');

                jQuery('#carousel .row').each(function(){
                    var max = Math.max.apply(null, jQuery('h4.title',this).map(function(){return jQuery(this).height()}).get());
                    jQuery('h4.title', this).css('min-height', max);
                });
                jQuery('#carousel').height(jQuery('#carousel .row').height());

                jQuery('#carousel').serialScroll({
                    axis: 'y',
                    cycle: false,
                    constant: false,
                    force: true,
                    items: '.row',
                    prev: '#carousel_nav .prev',
                    next: '#carousel_nav .next',
                    onBefore: function(e,elem,$pane,$items,pos){
                        $pane.height(jQuery(elem).height());
                    }
                });
            }
        }<?php

    }

}
?>

});
</script>
```

I haven't managed yet to add it, because of the php part inside the script. I don't know how to separate the javascript from the php and add it the right way to the footer.php.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your php code from script and put you script in one file suppose name custom-script.js

then add this js with wp_enqueue_script in your theme functions.php file

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    if ( is_home() ) {

       if ( option::get('featured_posts_show') == 'on' ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('custom-script',get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',  array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

Comment: I'm afraid that's not going to work. There are several php options in the code as well, like this:
animation: '<?php echo option::get('slideshow_effect') == 'Slide' ? 'slide' : 'fade'; ?>',
How to deal with those, because I need those options?

Comment: As per the mark told in his answer you can use wp_localize_script() like as follow

`$slider_option = array('slideshow_effect'=>$slide) // $slide is your option value for slider
wp_localize_script( 'custom-script', 'slider_option', $slider_option );`

after that you can use this varible in js as follows

`animation:slider_option.slideshow_effect `

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this, but it make sense. I'll come back when I'm stuck again.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Datta Parad's answer, use [wp_localize_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to get your dynamic values.

See the Codex (link above) and [Pippin's article](http://pippinsplugins.com/use-wp_localize_script-it-is-awesome/) for guidance on use.